# Error in bundle passing

Tags: java, android

I have 3 activities.In **product_dtls.java**  I have two buttons,**add2cart** and **image button**.It intents to add2crt activity on clicking add2cart button or image button.But,add2cart button also add product to database. **add2cart.java** has a **place button**,on click intents to **buy_ltr.java** where I set data from bundle in edittexts.Problem is that,If I get into buy_ltr.java by clicking add2cart button the edit text are not set with values.But image button clicks works fine.

**product_dtls.java**

```
public class Product_Details extends Activity{

TextView name,price,specification,feature;
String nme;
SQLiteDatabase mydb;
String pname;
String prprice;
String pspec;
String pfeature;
Button add2cart,by_nw;
ImageView image;
ImageButton imgbtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.product_dtls);
    image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pr_img);
    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPr_name);
    price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtprice);
    specification=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtPr_spec);
    feature=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtPr_feature);
    imgbtn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.cartimg);
    add2cart=(Button)findViewById(R.id.add2cart);
    by_nw=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buy_nw);

    Intent in = getIntent();
    Bundle bn = in.getExtras();
    Bundle bun=in.getExtras();
    final String dtl=bun.getString("key");
    nme = bn.getString("name");
    mydb = Product_Details.this.openOrCreateDatabase("products", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    Cursor cr = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM product WHERE pname = '"+nme+"'", null);

    while(cr.moveToNext())
    {
        String name = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("pname"));
        String pr1price = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("pprice"));
        String prspc=cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("pspec"));
        String prfeature=cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("pfeature"));
        pname = name;
        prprice = pr1price;
        pspec=prspc;
        pfeature=prfeature;
    }
    name.setText(pname);
    price.setText("Rs " +prprice + "/-");
    specification.setText(pspec);
    feature.setText(pfeature);


    add2cart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            boolean incart=false;
            String nm=name.getText().toString();
            mydb=Product_Details.this.openOrCreateDatabase("addcart", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            Cursor cur=mydb.rawQuery("select * from add2cart where pnme='"+nm+"'",null);

            if (cur.moveToFirst()){
                String prdname=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("pnme"));

                if (nm.equals(prdname)){
                    add2cart.setText("Already in Cart");
                    incart=true;
                }
            }

            if(incart==false){
                mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO add2cart (pnme,prate)VALUES('"+nm+"','"+prprice+"')");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"add to cart",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent in=new Intent(Product_Details.this,add2cart.class);
                startActivity(in);

            }

        }
    });


    by_nw.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent in=new Intent(Product_Details.this,buy_nw.class);
            Bundle bund = new Bundle();
            bund.putString("key",dtl);
            in.putExtras(bund);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
    imgbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent in=new Intent(Product_Details.this,add2cart.class);
            Bundle bundl = new Bundle();
            bundl.putString("dtls",dtl);
            in.putExtras(bundl);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });

}

}
```

**add2cart.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add2crt);
    adlstvw=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstvw_add2crt);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.place_order);

    //check bundle has null value

     if (bundl != null) {
     sme= bundl.getString("dtls");        
     }


    mydb=add2cart.this.openOrCreateDatabase("addcart", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    Cursor cr = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM add2cart", null);
    String [] pname = new String[cr.getCount()];
    String [] price = new String[cr.getCount()];

    int i = 0;
    while(cr.moveToNext())
    {
        String name = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("pnme"));
        String prprice = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("prate"));
        pname[i] = name;
        price[i] = prprice;
        i++;
    }
    CartAdapter cart=new CartAdapter(this,pname,price);
    adlstvw.setAdapter(cart);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent in=new Intent(add2cart.this,buy_ltr.class); 
            Bundle bndl = new Bundle();
            bndl.putString("som",sme); 
            in.putExtras(bndl);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: did you properly close and open the cursor ?

Comment: what is at line `46` in `add2cart`?

Comment: *Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.power.it.solar.add2cart.onCreate(add2cart.java:46)* check your line 46 !!

Comment: and where you initialized your Button `add2cart`?

Comment: if line number 46 is while(cr.moveToNext()) then check length of cursor , if it is more then 0 then and then iterate. if(cr.getCount()>0) { while(cr.moveToNext()) { } }

Comment: what code is there at line number 27

Comment: Have you created any DBHelper class in your project....

Comment: it seems like that you have not put any extras as string before starting your activity(add2cart).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's so normal to get `NullPointerException`, which came first(egg or chicken), you assign the value of `sme` by getting the String `dtls` from the Bundle of the activity:

```
final String sme=bundl.getString("dtls");
```

AND, you assign the value of `dtls` by attaching to the Bundle the value of `sme` which you in first declared by getting the value of `dtls`:

```
bundl.putString("dtls",sme);
```

SO, you just said :

```
int x, y;
x = y;
y = x;
```

So, what is the value of `x` and `y` then? it's **NULL**.

So, to overcome that, you must at the first run of the activity `add2cart.java` assign another value to `sme`, there are a lot of ways, one of them is to create a `static` variable to catch the first run of the activity:

```
public class add2cart extends Activity{
ListView adlstvw;
Button btn,remove_btn;
SQLiteDatabase mydb;
public static boolean first_init = true;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add2crt);
    adlstvw=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstvw_add2crt);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.place_order);
    if(first_init){
      final String sme = "some_value";
      first_init = false;
    }else{
     Intent in=getIntent();
     Bundle bundl=in.getExtras();
     final String sme=bundl.getString("dtls");
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

## To test `add2cart` Button:

```
add2cart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean incart=false;
        String nm=name.getText().toString();
        mydb=Product_Details.this.openOrCreateDatabase("addcart", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        System.out.println("Database Opened"); //here
        Cursor cur=mydb.rawQuery("select * from add2cart where pnme='"+nm+"'",null);
        System.out.println("Query Excuted"); //here
        if (cur.moveToFirst()){
            String prdname=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("pnme"));
            System.out.println(prdname); //here
            if (nm.equals(prdname)){
                add2cart.setText("Already in Cart");
                incart=true;
            }
        }

        if(incart==false){
            mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO add2cart (pnme,prate)VALUES('"+nm+"','"+prprice+"')");
            System.out.println("inserted"); //here
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"add to cart",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent in=new Intent(Product_Details.this,add2cart.class);
            startActivity(in);

        }else{
            System.out.println("incart"); //here
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: it's not about product_dtls it's about add2cart, make your changes there

Comment: well, first of all glad it worked :), then you have to assign a default value for sme, so that you pass this value in the first time(when `first_init=true`), then the times after that time you can pass it regularly using your way(the retrieved value from the bundle)

Comment: I modified my code.now it works for image button.But not for add2cart button.

Comment: well, what do you mean by image button(which button), and with add2cart button you mean the button named `btn` ? and when it doesn't work, is it gives you any Exception or message in your log?

Comment: These two buttons are in my product_dtls.java. Image button(imgbtn) and add2cart button(add2cart).Its not giving any exception or log.It just leave edit texts blank.

Comment: well, your `intent` in `add2cart` Button seems to be created in a right way, So, I think the problem is in one of the many actions you do when the button clicked, So, you have to test it someway to see what causes the problem, I added a modified code in order to print some result after every action or comparison in this onClick method, kindly replace your code for the onClick with this and tell me what exactly printed in your log upon running it.

Answer (score 0):

move this line to ur oncreate..

```
btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.place_order);
```

change this too

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Intent in=new Intent(add2cart.this,buy_ltr.class);
    Bundle bundl = new Bundle();
    bundl.putString("dtls",sme);
    in.putExtras(bundl);
    startActivity(in);
}
```

**edit:**

comment these line on add2cart

here u r not passing any values...

```
Intent in=new Intent(Product_Details.this,add2cart.class);
     startActivity(in);
```

cos of this code its landing to add2cart activity without values so ur getting error..

**edit2:**

```
  by_nw.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent in=new Intent(Product_Details.this,buy_nw.class);
            Bundle bund = new Bundle();
            bund.putString("key",dtl);
            in.putExtras(bund);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
    imgbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent in=new Intent(Product_Details.this,add2cart.class);
            Bundle bund = new Bundle();
            bund.putString("key",dtl);
            in.putExtras(bund);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
```

and in ur add2cart

```
final String sme=bundl.getString("key");
```